# Centralizer of semi-simple element in semi-simple Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a finite dimensional semi-simple Lie algebra, and $H$ a toral (maximal abelian) subalgebra. For any $h\in H$ I want to prove that $C_L(h)$ is reductive, i.e. its radical (=maximal solvable ideal) is equal to its center. How should I proceed?

What I did: Let $L=H\oplus (\bigoplus_{\alpha} L_a)$ be the root space decomposition of $L$ w.r.t. $H$. Let $L_{\alpha}=\langle x_{\alpha}\rangle.$ Then an element $h+\sum_{i=1}^k x_{\alpha_i}$  will commute with if and only if $h$ commutes with each $x_{\alpha_i}$. But $[h,x_{\alpha_i}]=\alpha_i(h)x_{\alpha_i}$ which forces that $\alpha_i(h)=0$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,k$.

After this I couldn't do anything. Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You have observed that $C_L(h)=\mathfrak h\oplus_{\alpha:\alpha(h)=0}\mathfrak g_{\alpha}$. Since this is the decomposition into joint eigenspaces for the adjoint action of $\mathfrak h\subset C_L(h)$, it follows from standard arguments (the projection onto an eigenspace of a linear map can be written as a polynomial in the map) that an $\mathfrak h$-invariant subspace of $C_L(\mathfrak h)$ must be the direct sum of a linear subspace of $\mathfrak h$ and some of the root spaces. In particular, this applies to any ideal in $C_L(\mathfrak h)$ and hence to the radical $\mathfrak r$. Now first argue directly that an ideal containing a root space cannot be solvable and second that an ideal contained in $\mathfrak h$ must actually be contained in the joint kernel of $\{\alpha:\alpha(h)=0\}$, which is exactly the center of $C_L(h)$.

Comment: You are completely right, I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Now I see that we're using that the Cartan subalgebra is split here. Maybe the question was secretly asked with the assumption that the ground field is algebraically closed, but I wonder if the assertion is true in the more general case, including for non-split CSA. One would hope that follows from this via scalar extension, but it is not entirely straightforward because taking centralisers does not necessarily commute with scalar extension. Do you see a way to prove the statement in general?

Comment: Looking at the question, I automatically thought that this deals with the complex case  and I was only thinking about that case. I don't know too much about Lie algebras over general fields.

Comment: Actually, never mind my earlier objection: First of all I do believe now that centralisers commute with scalar extension, secondly for toral subalgebras (=abelian and consisting of semisimple elements) the centraliser equals the normaliser and I have always believed that commutes with scalar extension. Finally, a Lie algebra is reductive iff a scalar extension of it is, so we can indeed reduce to the case of an algebraically closed field which you solve here.